# Check box in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a check box in shiny that allows me to change the signs of one of the input variables from positive to negative

From input:

```
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  numericInput(inputId = "CE",
               label = "...:",
               min = 0,
               max = 1,
               value = 0.001),
  checkboxInput("CHECKBOX","Checkbox", FALSE),
```

....

```
server <- function(input, output) 
output$Power_dropM <- renderText({
if(input$CHECKBOX=TRUE) {
  bzc <- -(sqrt(abs(input$CE)) * sign(input$CE))    
  bzm <- sqrt(abs(input$ME)) * sign(input$ME)   
}else{
bzc <- sqrt(abs(input$CE)) * sign(input$CE)     
bzm <- sqrt(abs(input$ME)) * sign(input$ME)     
}
```

These number generated are used further down stream so I want the naming to stay the same, just changing the sign by checking the box.

This code however, just give me an error:

```
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:/Users/ghmoen/Documents/SEM/ShinyApp210618.R:76:22: unexpected '='
75:     
76:     if(input$CHECKBOX=
                     ^
Error in sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing C:\Users\ghmoen\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2T3R18\file57b0565138b6
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Do you get an error? Please provide a good, minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've updated with the error I'm getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, your error is caused by `if(input$CHECKBOX=TRUE)`. To check for equality you need to use double `=`, so `if(input$CHECKBOX==TRUE)`. In this case it could even be simplified to `if(input$CHECKBOX)`, since your variable is boolean.

Bu the way, a slightly simpler approach  to change the sign might be to add a multiplier of `+1` or `-1` to the variable. For example, to just change the sign, you could do:

```
library(shiny)

# Create ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput('bzc','bzc',value=2),
  numericInput('bzm','bzm',value=2),
  checkboxInput('change_sign','Change sign'),
  textOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderText({
    bzc = ifelse(input$change_sign,-1,1) * input$bzc
    bzm = input$bzm
    paste0('bzc: ', bzc, ', bzm: ', bzm)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```